# how can i drag any label in vb

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I want to drag any label that is created in VB form. Is that possible if use a code to create a label?

For example: I have 20 labels and they are all different names. Is there a code that can let me drag any label I click on with the cursor I used that code it works but it only drags those labels that I created earlier but if I use a code to create labels is there a way to drag those:

code for dragging 1 label

code for click and drag 1 label only that was added in edit view

```
Private Sub obj1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)  'varocarbas
        ' Check if the mouse is down
        If Go = True Then
            ' Set the mouse position
            HoldLeft = (Control.MousePosition.X - Me.Left)
            HoldTop = (Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)
            ' Find where the mouse was clicked ONE TIME
            If TopSet = False Then
                OffTop = HoldTop - sender.Top
                ' Once the position is held, flip the switch
                ' so that it doesn't keep trying to find the position
                TopSet = True
            End If
            If LeftSet = False Then
                OffLeft = HoldLeft - sender.Left
                ' Once the position is held, flip the switch
                ' so that it doesn't keep trying to find the position
                LeftSet = True
            End If
            ' Set the position of the object
            sender.Left = HoldLeft - OffLeft
            sender.Top = HoldTop - OffTop
        End If

    End Sub
```

code for creating labels on form

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim lbl As New Label

        lbl.Name = "Label" & counter

        lbl.Size = New Size(80, 20)

        lbl.Location = New Point(80, counter * 22)

        lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text

        AddHandler lbl.MouseMove, AddressOf obj1_MouseMove 'varocarbas

        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

        counter += 1

    End Sub

End Class
```

I want to drag created labels. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating controls at runtime, additionally to populate the properties, you have to associate the corresponding methods to all the events you want. If you want to add `obj1_MouseMove` to `lbl` you would have to write:

```
AddHandler lbl.MouseMove, AddressOf obj1_MouseMove
```

And remove the `Handles obj1.MouseMove` bit from the method declaration.

Comment: thank you for your reply but could be more specific please i am looking for a code that will make every label on the form movable dispute the text or name of the label

Comment: @user2581791 I haven't tested your code (`obj1_MouseMove`). Is it not performing what you wish?

Comment: it works perfectly but it is only limiting to 1 label only but as i am using the program that will have a lot of labels and they are going be added at random i need a code that will make my form attached to the labels that i can click and drag any label on the form

Comment: @user2581791 bear in mind that your code is adapted to the given `sender`, that is, the given label. You can declare as many labels at runtime as you wish (with different properties) and add the code in this answer to each of them and your method will be able to recognise each label. That is, all the labels will have associated the same method but each label will be passing a different `sender` as argument.

Comment: thank you varocarbas could you please write that code i will appreciate that a lot because i am new to thatlabele moving stuff thank you

Comment: @user2581791 you have just to include this line in the declaration of each label (and replace `lbl` with the given label object). For example, in the code you posted, write this line below `lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text`. If you need further help, please post the code where you are declaring your labels and I can do a quick edit for you.

Comment: @user2581791 You just need to add the line I wrote (as it is) every time you add a label at runtime. Nothing else.

Comment: thank you varcarbas i am still confused that the that i am useing

Comment: @user2581791 I have edited your question for you. See? You just have to add the code in my answer while defining the label. Do that (every time the same) for each label and your method (obj1_MouseMove) will be able to distinguish between them automatically. Clearer now?

Comment: You are welcome. Well... it is a bit excessive to say this for just this answer, but thanks ;)

Comment: @user2581791 why you keep intending to edit my answer? Just tell me whatever you want via comment. What did you mean? To write your whole corrected code as my answer and let your original code as it was initially?